# Discord.py - Making a command only available in a specific channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been trying to make a way to make a way for this command to only work in a specific channel but nothing seems to work. I'm new to discord.py so I don't know a lot.

```
 @client.command(case_sensitive=True)
    async def resus(ctx,*, saymsg=None):
        if saymsg==None:
            return await ctx.send("To reserve a username type - !resus (your discord tag) (the username you want) (if you want verification)!")
    
    
        sayEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name} Said", color = discord.Color.blue(), description=f"{saymsg}")
        sayEmbed.timestamp = ctx.message.created_at
        channelf = client.get_channel(873564203535958047)
        await channelf.send(embed = sayEmbed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`checks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#checks)

> A check is a basic predicate that can take in a Context as its sole parameter. Within it, you have the following options:
>
> - Return `True` to signal that the person `can run` the command.
> - Return `False` to signal that the person `cannot run` the command.
> - Raise a CommandError derived exception to signal the person cannot run the command.
>   This allows you to have custom error messages for you to handle in the error handlers.

```py
async def is_channel(ctx):
    return ctx.channel.id == 123456789


@client.command(case_sensitive=True)
@commands.check(is_channel)
    async def resus(ctx,*, saymsg=None):
```